# Bitmap that is larger Width than Height appears landscaped in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I am getting a bitmap from a server which is wider than it is high eg height = 612, width = 816 and putting it in an ImageView that is: Height = 568 and Width =320. The image that comes from the server appears landscaped in the imageview, that is, it appears on its side. [image]However I want to scale it to fit the ImageViews dimensions. I tried a lot of different scale types, `fitXY` i thought would fix it but it is still the same. Below is my xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="568dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

Comment: scale down the  bitmap

Comment: I also tried this but it was almost unreadable

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

in res folder :
make value-land folder 
and thenmake dimen.xml
put these height widht value in it

like:

```
 <dimen name="image_widht">816dp</dimen>`
<dimen name="image_height">612dp</dimen>
```

in your image view :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_widht"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_heigh"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

also you have make dimension xml in value folder for potrate 
and put the dimension with same name with differnt value whicjh you want

Comment: How will this help, can you further explain please?

Comment: when change the orientation it will automatically pic the value-land folder for dimension

Comment: I do not want to change the image when the device orientation is changed. The Image from server appears landscaped when the device is in the portrait mode. Please see above

Comment: if any concern you can ask me

Comment: brother its working i already implemented in my code . i thing you are missing something. you are making two files dimens.xml in both value and value-land folder and giving there heght and widht same dimension name in both the dimen.xml file

Comment: I followed your instructions, I have 2 folders in res called `values` and `values-land`, but the image above in the question is still the same, the correct image is 90 degrees on the server but image view shows it like above